# Dynamic Space-Filling DIV Widths

Tags: css, css-float, width

I am working on a client site that is driven by EE.

They have a page of technical documents, each with titles of varying length, as well as brief descriptions, also of varying length. In between the two, their design calls for a spacer with leader dots:

[image: sScreen grab from PDF]

For each line item, I have a container and floating DIVs for the title and description:

```
<div class="cv-lit-lineitem">           
    <div class="cv-lit-title"><h3>Title</h3></div>
    <div class="cv-lit-linespacer"></div>
    <div class="cv-lit-info"><p>Info</p></div>
</div>
```

The title and info float left and right respectively, and their width is defined by their contents:

```
.cv-lit-lineitem {
    height: 40px;
    width: 940px;
}

.cv-lit-title {
    height: 16px;
    float: left;
}

.cv-lit-linespacer {
    background-image: url("whitedots.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
}

.cv-lit-info {
    height: 16px;
    float: right;
}
```

I can't seem to get the spacer div to fill the space inbetween. Setting it to 100% fills the entire container width, and everything else results in a width of 0.

Do I need to employ javascript, or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks for any help,

ty

PS: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tylonius/zC8jZ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;`

[**Check this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/p8xaz/)

HTML

```
<div class="cv-lit-lineitem">             
    <div class="cv-lit-title"><h3>Title</h3></div>
    <div class="cv-lit-linespacer"></div>
    <div class="cv-lit-info"><p>Info</p></div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.cv-lit-lineitem {
    height: 40px;
    width: 940px;
    display:table;
}
.cv-lit-lineitem > div {
    display:table-cell;
}   
.cv-lit-title {
    height: 16px;
}
.cv-lit-linespacer {
    background-image: url("whitedots.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}    
.cv-lit-info {
    height: 16px;
}​
```

Unfortunately, this won't work on IE8 and below.

---

Another simple workaround is to put the dots in the container's background, then cover it with title's and info's backgrounds. But this works only if you have a single-color page background.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/2mxCh/)

Comment: It has to work on IE8, and no the background is not a single color (that was actually the first approach I took).

Comment: I tried this and it sort of works. It made the surrounding divs as small as possible, though, which was the length of the longest word. To make it work the way it needs to, the client would have to put non-breaking spaces and hyphens between every word. Any other ideas?

Comment: @TyMorton have you tried adding some padding (left and right) to `.cv-lit-title` and `.cv-lit-info` ? Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/8x3w9/

Comment: Yes, it actually had some padding to begin with. I truncated it out of the example CSS here.